# JS code not being accepted in freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working through freecodecamp and am on the following excercise:

https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup

Now my code is as follows:

```js
var contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "lastName": "Laine",
  "number": "0543236543",
  "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Harry",
  "lastName": "Potter",
  "number": "0994372684",
  "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Sherlock",
  "lastName": "Holmes",
  "number": "0487345643",
  "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Kristian",
  "lastName": "Vos",
  "number": "unknown",
  "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  // Only change code below this line

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name) {
      foundName += 1;
    }
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    } else if (contacts[i].firstName == name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) == false) {
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
  if (foundName < 1) {
    return "No such contact"
  };
}

var foundName = 0;

// Only change code above this line


// Change these values to test your function
var ans = lookUpProfile("Bob", "number");
console.log(ans);
```

So I'm looping through the pre-defined array with my for loop and I'm checking for instances where name == firstName and where the object has a property of prop. In these instances I am returning the property. Otherwise, I return "No such Property". I'm also changing my variable foundName so that when firstName is matched to name in the loop, foundName gets a positive value. IF foundName is less than 1 (i.e. no name matches found) then I return 'No such contact'.

Now, when I run this in my browser and look in the console it seems to work perfectly. However, when I enter this answer into freecodecamp, I get:

"Bob", "number" should return "No such contact"
"Bob", "potato" should return "No such contact"

But if I put, for example, "Bob" and "number" into the function, I do get "no such contact"... I must be missing something obvious here but I am extremely confused by this!!

Comment: You're missing `var contacts = [` before the array at the beginning of the code.

Comment: You never initialize `foundName` to `0`. You should just use a boolean `true/false` for this, BTW.

Comment: Here's all you need: `var match = contacts.filter(c => c.firstName === name);
if (!match.length) return "No such contact";
return match[0][prop] || "No such property";`

Comment: Sorry I didn't copy the var contacts = [ over but it was there in my code - I've added it now. And I do initialize foundName to 0.

Comment: @ChrisG That's way better, but maybe too advanced for him, I think he is just starting off with JavaScript ;)

Comment: @Ivan yep that's right!! To be fair, I know there will be loads of ways to solve this. What I don't understand is why freecodecamp is rejecting my code when, when I run this in my console, all the required results appear fine

Comment: I can't see the reason, either.

Comment: on freecodecamp do you have a sort of editor to test it?

Comment: Yes. Actually problem solved now - you were right, simple scope issue :). Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your variable **foundName** every time you call the function **lookUpProfile** you change the global variable **foundName** so when you call the function ** lookUpProfile** with 'bob' as argument it will return **undefined** because the value of **foundName** is greater that 1 , so you need to scope the variable to the function block scope , you should define the varaible **foundName** inside the function not outside it  , also stop using the key word **var** and instead use **let**

look at the solution below

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  // Only change code below this line
   let foundName = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name) {
      foundName += 1;
    }
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    } else if (contacts[i].firstName == name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) == false) {
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
  if (foundName < 1) {
    return "No such contact"
  };
}




// Only change code above this line


// Change these values to test your function
// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Comment: Aha! Awesome. Thank you very much - can't believe it was just a scoping issue !

Comment: Great continue solving more problems and challenges , and when you have a problem we're always here to help .

Answer (score 0):

You object declaration is not correct: `contacts` is an Array.

The function works but you need to keep `foundName` enclosed in the function rather than outside. Otherwise, if you run your function twice it will break.

Here is the working code:

```js
const contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "lastName": "Laine",
  "number": "0543236543",
  "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Harry",
  "lastName": "Potter",
  "number": "0994372684",
  "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Sherlock",
  "lastName": "Holmes",
  "number": "0487345643",
  "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Kristian",
  "lastName": "Vos",
  "number": "unknown",
  "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

  let foundName = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name) {
      foundName += 1;
    }
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    } else if (contacts[i].firstName == name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) == false) {
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
  if (foundName < 1) {
    return "No such contact"
  };
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"))
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "number"))
```

Comment: The object declaration problem was just a copying error.

Comment: Putting that first made it seem like that was your main point, and the `foundName` issue was less important.

Comment: Well it seemed pretty important at the time because the code didn't run. The second only affects the execution when the function is called more than once

Comment: Yeah. I upvoted the other answer because he went into more detail about why this is the serious problem.

Comment: @Barmar, true, I understand